# member data is not inherited properly

Tags: c++, class, for-loop

I'm new to C++, and I'm having a rather weird problem. My code must have 2 base classes and 1 derived class. In the member function `calculo` of the derived class, the for cycles are ignored and wont do anything, and I can't figure out why. I understand that the derived class will inheret the base classes' public and protected stuff, but when I check the memory direction of the same member data (`num_r1`) in function `datos()` and function `calculo()` it gives me a different memory direction.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class base1//circuito serie
{
protected:
    int num_r1;//numero de resistores
    float r1[50];//valores de cada resistor
    int f1;//numero de filas de matriz uno
    int c1;//numero de columnas de matriz uno
    float m1[50][50];//filas de la primer matriz;//columnas de la primer matriz
public:
    void datos();//resistores
    void datos(int);//matriz [suma o producto]
    base1(){};
    ~base1(){cout<<"Destructor de clase base1"<<endl;};
};

class base2//circuito paralelo
{
protected:
    int num_r2;//numero de resistores
    float r2[50];//valores de cada resistor
    int f2;//numero de filas de matriz dos
    int c2;//numero de columnas de matriz dos
    float m2[50][50];//filas de la segunda matriz//columnas de la segunda matriz
public:
    void datos();//resistores
    void datos(int);//matriz [suma o producto]
    base2(){};
    ~base2(){cout<<"Destructor de clase base2"<<endl;};
};

class derivada:public base1, public base2
{
    float rt1;//resistencia total serie
    float rt2;//resistencia total paralelo
    float m3[50][50];//matriz resultante de suma
    float m4[50][50];//matriz resultante de producto
public:
    void calculo();
    void imprimir();
    derivada(){};
    ~derivada(){cout<<"Destructor de clase derivada"<<endl;};
};

//[...]

void derivada::calculo()
{
    rt1=0;
    for(int c=0;c<num_r1;c++)//serie
        {
            rt1=rt1+r1[c];
        }
    float a;
    rt2=0;
    for(int c=0;c<num_r2;c++)
        {
           a=(a+(1/r2[c]));
        }
        rt2=(1/a);
}

void derivada::imprimir()
{
    cout<<"RESULTADOS"<<endl;
    for(int x=0;x<num_r1;x++)
        {
            cout<<"\tResistencia ["<<x+1<<"]: "<<r1[x]<<" ohms"<<endl;
        }
    cout<<"Resistencia total en serie = "<<rt1<<" ohms"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int OP;
    base1 a;
    base2 b;
    derivada c;
    a.datos();
    b.datos();
    cout<<"Desea realizar una suma (1) o producto (2) de matrices?: "<<endl;
    cout<<"(?): ";
    cin>>OP;
    a.datos(OP);
    b.datos(OP);
    c.calculo();
    c.imprimir();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include a [mcve] (maybe code can be reduced), input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: i think i already cut as much as possible, sorry if its messy or if its too much code

Comment: `num_r1` is never initialized, it could have any value. If it is zero, the loop will do nothing.

Comment: lmao i just find out what was my problem, it was weird to work with 4 functions called datos, i made datos1(),datos2(),datos1(int) and datos2(int) and now it works!

Comment: how can i initialize it tho, with the constructor? or is there a way to do it just like i posted the code?

Comment: You can initialize it in the ctor or make some setter, but that depends on the logic of  your program. Anyway, you must initialize it with the correct value before start using it in any loop.

Comment: Is "memory direction" supposed to be "memory address"?

Comment: yes, sorry for my broken english xd